# Android Cordova app crash on startup: Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed

Tags: android, cordova

I have an app that behaves fine in ios, but crashes on Android devices on startup.  Some. Not all. It crashus a Nexus 7 running lollipop, works fine on a Pixel 2 running Nougat. When I test it at Amazon's Device Testing service, I get this mixed bag of results:

[image: Amazon Kindle device crash list]

```
--------- beginning of crash
    02-22 12:47:02.587 18315-18370/net.mydomain.bingo A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 18370 (Thread-399)
    02-22 12:47:02.930 1139-1139/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1139: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
    02-22 12:47:02.933 1499-1616/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '32d81f42 net.mydomain.bingo/net.mydomain.bingo.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    02-22 12:47:02.934 1499-1616/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '176d8224 net.mydomain.bingo/net.mydomain.bingo.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    02-22 12:47:02.934 1499-1616/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '3bf3ddb6 net.mydomain.bingo/net.mydomain.bingo.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
    02-22 12:47:02.979 1136-1136/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error opening /proc/18315/oom_score_adj; errno=2
```

Amazon graphs memory use, and it never approaches the heap limit on any of the reports. CPU use rises to around 30% on load, but does the same on the devices that successfully run the thing. How can I get a more helpful report of what's going on here than

```
Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

That gives me no indication where in my mainactivity code I'm going wrong. My suspicion is a block of code that loads a bingo board into a set of two arrays:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').on('touchmove', false);

//  $('#header').append(headerText);
    $('#header').append(headerImage);


    $('#footer').append(footerText);
    shuffle(JSONBingo.squares);

    for (i=0; i<24; i++)    {
        if (i==12) {
            $('#board').append("<div data-value='1' class='selected freesquare' id='sqfree'><p class='text hyphens noselect'><br/>free space</p></div>");
            $('#board').append("<div data-value='0' class='square' id='sq12'><p class='text hyphens noselect'><br/>"+JSONBingo.squares[i].square+"</p></div>");
        } else {
            $('#board').append("<div data-value='0' class='square' id='sq"+i+"'><p class='text hyphens noselect'><br/>"+JSONBingo.squares[i].square+"</p></div>");

        }

  }

shuffle(JSONBingoPLUS.squaresPLUS);  

for (i=0; i<24; i++)    {

        if (i==12) {
            $('#positiveboard').append("<div data-value='1' class='selected freesquarePLUS' id='sqfreePLUS'><p class='text hyphens noselect'><br/>free space</p></div>");
            $('#positiveboard').append("<div data-value='0' class='squarePLUS' id='sqp12'><p class='text hyphens noselect'><br/>"+JSONBingoPLUS.squaresPLUS[i].squarePLUS+"</p></div>");
        } else {
            $('#positiveboard').append("<div data-value='0' class='squarePLUS' id='sqp"+i+"'><p class='text hyphens noselect'><br/>"+JSONBingoPLUS.squaresPLUS[i].squarePLUS+"</p></div>");
        }

  }


    $('div.square').tappable(function ()  {
       cancelOnMove: false;
      if (!event.target.id){ 
      } else {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');

      if ($(this).data('value') == 1) {


            $(this).data('value', 0);}
      else {

            $(this).data('value', 1); 

            }
            }



         clickSnd.play();

        var row1 = ($('#sq0').data('value')+$('#sq1').data('value')+$('#sq2').data('value')+$('#sq3').data('value')+$('#sq4').data('value'));
        var row2 = ($('#sq5').data('value')+$('#sq6').data('value')+$('#sq7').data('value')+$('#sq8').data('value')+$('#sq9').data('value'));
        var row3 = ($('#sq10').data('value')+$('#sq11').data('value')+$('#sqfree').data('value')+$('#sq12').data('value')+$('#sq13').data('value'));
        var row4 = ($('#sq14').data('value')+$('#sq15').data('value')+$('#sq16').data('value')+$('#sq17').data('value')+$('#sq18').data('value'));  
        var row5 = ($('#sq19').data('value')+$('#sq20').data('value')+$('#sq21').data('value')+$('#sq22').data('value')+$('#sq23').data('value'));          

        var col1 = ($('#sq0').data('value')+$('#sq5').data('value')+$('#sq10').data('value')+$('#sq14').data('value')+$('#sq19').data('value'));
        var col2 = ($('#sq1').data('value')+$('#sq6').data('value')+$('#sq11').data('value')+$('#sq15').data('value')+$('#sq20').data('value'));
        var col3 = ($('#sq2').data('value')+$('#sq7').data('value')+$('#sqfree').data('value')+$('#sq16').data('value')+$('#sq21').data('value'));
        var col4 = ($('#sq3').data('value')+$('#sq8').data('value')+$('#sq12').data('value')+$('#sq17').data('value')+$('#sq22').data('value'));    
        var col5 = ($('#sq4').data('value')+$('#sq9').data('value')+$('#sq13').data('value')+$('#sq18').data('value')+$('#sq23').data('value'));            

        var diag1 = ($('#sq0').data('value')+$('#sq6').data('value')+$('#sqfree').data('value')+$('#sq17').data('value')+$('#sq23').data('value')); 
        var diag2 = ($('#sq4').data('value')+$('#sq8').data('value')+$('#sqfree').data('value')+$('#sq15').data('value')+$('#sq19').data('value')); 

        if (row1 == 5 || row2 == 5 || row3 == 5 || row4 == 5 || row5 == 5 || col1 == 5 || col2 == 5 || col3 == 5  || col4 == 5  || col5 == 5 || diag1 == 5 || diag2 == 5) {
            $('#header').html(loseText);
            $('#header').addClass("lose");

            loseSnd.play();

        } else {
            $('#header').html(headerImage);
            $('#header').removeClass("lose");

        }; 
    });

        $('div.squarePLUS').tappable(function ()  {
       cancelOnMove: false;
      if (!event.target.id){ 
      } else {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');

      if ($(this).data('valuePLUS') == 1) {


            $(this).data('valuePLUS', 0);}
      else {

            $(this).data('valuePLUS', 1); 

            }
            }



         clickSnd.play();

        var row1 = ($('#sqp0').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp1').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp2').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp3').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp4').data('valuePLUS'));
        var row2 = ($('#sqp5').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp6').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp7').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp8').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp9').data('valuePLUS'));
        var row3 = ($('#sqp10').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp11').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqfreePLUS').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp12').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp13').data('valuePLUS'));
        var row4 = ($('#sqp14').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp15').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp16').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp17').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp18').data('valuePLUS')); 
        var row5 = ($('#sqp19').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp20').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp21').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp22').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp23').data('valuePLUS'));         

        var col1 = ($('#sqp0').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp5').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp10').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp14').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp19').data('valuePLUS'));
        var col2 = ($('#sqp1').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp6').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp11').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp15').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp20').data('valuePLUS'));
        var col3 = ($('#sqp2').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp7').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqfreePLUS').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp16').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp21').data('valuePLUS'));
        var col4 = ($('#sqp3').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp8').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp12').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp17').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp22').data('valuePLUS'));   
        var col5 = ($('#sqp4').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp9').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp13').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp18').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp23').data('valuePLUS'));           

        var diag1 = ($('#sqp0').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp6').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqfreePLUS').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp17').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp23').data('valuePLUS')); 
        var diag2 = ($('#sqp4').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp8').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqfreePLUS').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp15').data('valuePLUS')+$('#sqp19').data('valuePLUS')); 

        if (row1 == 5 || row2 == 5 || row3 == 5 || row4 == 5 || row5 == 5 || col1 == 5 || col2 == 5 || col3 == 5  || col4 == 5  || col5 == 5 || diag1 == 5 || diag2 == 5) {
            $('#header').html(winText);
            $('#header').addClass("win");

            winSnd.play();

        } else {
            $('#header').html(headerText);
            $('#header').removeClass("win");

        }; 
    });

});


shuffle = function(v){
        for(var j, x, i = v.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = v[--i], v[i] = v[j], v[j] = x);
        return v;
};
```

Any ideas? My brain hurts from trying to chase this down for days now...

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand the log, and I'll give a green check to anyone who can parse it, but was able to determine the suspect script was not the issue: by commenting it out and reuploading, I still got the crashes.

The problem was an index.js file, which I'd snagged as a possible solution to a plugin load problem and which I'd forgotten was in my js directory.  I had put a different document.ready script in the  element of my html instead, and when I removed the index.js physically from the directory the crashes stopped. And don't know if this lesson is of use to anyone, but after the index.js file didn't work to solve my issue, I'd just removed the  reference from the html, forgetting Node will load index.js first if present, regardless if it's referenced in the index.html. So I had an entire block of ghost code that was compiling and which I didn't think was there.

The index.js:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

And the script I put in the  element of my html:

```
   <script>
    function onDeviceReady () {

    }
 function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

</script>
```